# Check layer data type in gdb

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, describe-object

I have path to layer or feature

```
C:\base.gdb\test
```

How to check is table or feature class by arcpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use Describe Object property [dataType](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000013000000):

```
desc = arcpy.Describe("C:/base.gdb/test")
if desc.dataType == 'FeatureClass':
    print 'fc'
elif desc.dataType == 'Table':
    print 'table'
else: print desc.dataType
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the arcpy.List... functions.
First have to set the env.workspace to the fgdb.
Then use arcpy.ListTables() or arcpy.ListFeatureclasses().
Each of these returns a python list of the requested type.
If the list is empty (len(list) == 0), then there is no thing of that type.
Unfortunately there does not seem to be a higher level function like arcpy.ListContents() or something.