# Exporting lists of Feature classes and fields from SDE

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, csv

I'm using matt wilkies' arcplus module https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5943/16793 to export a list of feature classes within an SDE database to a text file.   I've also written a tool to write field names to a csv file:

```
   """The source code of the tool."""
  import arcpy, os, csv


fclass = "SDEConnection\\"+Feature
fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass)]
writepath = r"C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TableFields\\"+Feature+".csv"
with open(writepath, "w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
        for val in fieldnames:
    writer.writerow([val])
```

Ideally, I'd like to loop through the feature classes and fields and write a write file containing something like below:

Feature Class or Table-----------------------------------Fields

WELLS.WELL_DATA-------------------------------------WELL_KEY, SITEID, DEPTH, DIAMETER

I'm a little stumped on nesting the loops and formatting the output like this.

-----------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------

Using the Walk method with a script like this

```
import os, arcpy, csv
def inventory_data(workspace, datatypes):
for path, path_names, data_names in arcpy.da.Walk(
        workspace, datatype=datatypes):
    for data_name in data_names:
        yield os.path.join(path, data_name)
```

obtains a unicode string like **"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\Connection to oracle.sde\BASINS\BASINS.ONE"**

while

```
fn = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
print fn
```

extracts a list

**[u'FNODE_', u'TNODE_', u'LPOLY_', u'RPOLY_',]**

My aim is to combine Walk with ListFields in a loop and write the FeatureClass with its accompanying fields (delimited) to a file.

Comment: I asked a similar question here which outputs to a text file if a certain field contains a link that doesn't exist within the database. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76900/hyperlink-broken-path-python-check

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example you can reference.  It prints the results to both the console and to a text file, but you could easily manipulate it to write to a .csv file.

Hope this helps.

-ST

```
Results :

Feature Class Name : CR.CANADA1  
Geometry Type      : Polygon  
Has Spatial Index  : True  
Spatial Reference  : GCS_North_American_1927
  Field Name : CR.CANADA1.AREA       Field Type : Double            Field Length : 8
  Field Name : CODE                  Field Type : String            Field Length : 4
  Field Name : NAME                  Field Type : String            Field Length : 25
  Field Name : POP1991               Field Type : Double            Field Length : 8
  Field Name : POP91_SQMI            Field Type : Double            Field Length : 8
  Field Name : SHAPE                 Field Type : Geometry          Field Length : 4
  Field Name : SHAPE.AREA            Field Type : Double            Field Length : 0
  Field Name : SHAPE.LEN             Field Type : Double            Field Length : 0
  Field Name : SHAPE.FID             Field Type : OID               Field Length : 0
# of Fields in Feature Class 'CR.CANADA1' = 9
```

---

```
CODE :

import arcpy

logfile = open(r'C:\TEMP\ListFCs_ListFieldNames_ListFieldTypes.log', 'w')

def log_results(message):
    print(message)
    logfile.write(message)
    logfile.flush()
    return

def main():
    try:
        wk = arcpy.env.workspace = 'Database Connections/ORCL - SDE@SRVRNAME.sde'
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")
        fcList.sort()

        if not arcpy.Exists(wk):
            log_results("\n" + " SDE Connection File DOES NOT EXIST!!\n")
        else:
            fcCnt = 0
            fldCnt = 0

            for fc in fcList:
                fcCnt += 1
                desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
                log_results ("\n Feature Class Name : {0}  \n Geometry Type      : {1}  \n Has Spatial Index  : {2}  \n Spatial Reference  : {3}".format(fc,desc.shapeType,str(desc.hasSpatialIndex),desc.spatialReference.name))
                #field = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
                fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
                fldCnt = 0
                for field in fields:
                    log_results ("\n    Field Name : {0: <24}  Field Type : {1: <20}  Field Length : {2}".format(field.name, field.type, field.length))
                    fldCnt += 1
                log_results ("\n # of Fields in Feature Class '{0}' = {1} \n".format(fc, fldCnt))

        log_results ("\n TOTAL # OF FEATURE CLASSES LISTED = {0}".format(fcCnt))
        log_results ("\n\n COMPLETED!! \n")

        logfile.close()

    except arcpy.ExecuteError:
        log_results (arcpy.GetMessages(2))

    except Exception as e:
        log_results (e[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Loop through geodatabase (to get list of feature classes)**

Use [Walk (arcpy.da)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000) method

Once you have the feature class you may want to verify data type (feature class, table,....etc) before you start the list field loop.  To do this you may use the Describe [Object property dataType](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000013000000).  For checking data type you may reference this Q/A:

[Check layer data type in gdb](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108865/check-layer-data-type-in-gdb/108870#108870)

**Get field list**

Use the [ListFields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000012000000) mehtod

Comment: I can use the walk method to generate a list of the feature classes, but I also want to use the ListFields method to loop through each feature class and ideally, generate a comma delimited list of fields in a separate column